# Kotlin: passing data from fragment to recyclerview

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a recyclerview with products that are loaded in trough my API. When you click on a product you get send to the info page where there is a button that adds that product to a new recyclerview. But I have no idea how to send that product to my 'wishlist' recyclerview.
Link to the project: https://github.com/arfeen14/arfeenShopApp

Fragment where the list of products are loaded in from the API.

```
`
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel
    private lateinit var notificationsViewModel: NotificationsViewModel

    private val popularProducts = arrayListOf<Producten>()
    private val popularProductsAdapter =
        MainProductAdapter(popularProducts, onClickListener = this::clickOnPopularProduct)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        dashboardViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity())[DashboardViewModel::class.java]
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)

        val rvPopularProducten: RecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.rvPopularProducts)
        //rv van category
        val rvCategory: RecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.rvCategories)

        // connect the adapters to the recyclerviews
        rvPopularProducten.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(this.context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        rvPopularProducten.adapter = popularProductsAdapter

        loadData()

        return root
    }


    fun loadData() {
        dashboardViewModel.getProducts()
        popularProducts.clear()

        dashboardViewModel.product.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer {
                this.popularProducts.clear()
                popularProducts.addAll(it.products)
                popularProductsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            })
    }


    private fun clickOnPopularProduct(view: View, product: Producten) {
        val transaction = requireFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        val productInfoFragment = ProductInfoFragment()

        productInfoFragment.geselecteerdeProduct = product

        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, productInfoFragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()

    }
}
```

This is where the product info is showed when you click on a product.

```
 class ProductInfoFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var productInfoViewModel: ProductInfoViewModel
    var geselecteerdeProduct: Producten? = null

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        productInfoViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProductInfoViewModel::class.java)


        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_info, container, false)

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            root.tvProducInfo_info.text =
                Html.fromHtml(geselecteerdeProduct!!.bodyHtml, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
        } else {
            root.tvProducInfo_info.text = Html.fromHtml(geselecteerdeProduct!!.bodyHtml)
        }

        Glide.with(root.context).load(geselecteerdeProduct!!.imagePath.productImgPath)
            .into(root.imgProduct_info)
        root.tvProduct_info_name.text = "€ " + geselecteerdeProduct!!.variants[0].productPrice

        root.btnAddToWishList.setOnClickListener() {
            click()

        }
        return root
    }


    private fun click() {

    }
}
```

The recyclerview where I want my product if you clicked the addToWishListbtn.

```
class NotificationsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var notificationsViewModel: NotificationsViewModel
    val product = arrayListOf<Producten>()

    private val wenslijstAdapter =
        WenslijstAdapter(product)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        notificationsViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity())[NotificationsViewModel::class.java]

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false)
        val rvWenslijst: RecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.rvWenslijst1)




        rvWenslijst.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(this.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        rvWenslijst.adapter = wenslijstAdapter




        return root
    }


}
```

Comment: How do you actually navigate between 1 Fragment to another Fragment? There are about 4 ways to do it, so it's crucial to know in order to answer your question.

Comment: Oh, you have `R.id.nav_host_fragment`. That means you are using Jetpack Navigation. That means you did not include your `navigation.xml` and so your question cannot be answered. You are never supposed to replace the NavHostFragment with another Fragment, and you are never supposed to set arguments of a Fragment through public mutable field variables. Read #5 in https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0, your application will crash in production.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Kotlin get data from a clicked item in Recyclerview and pass it between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151721/android-kotlin-get-data-from-a-clicked-item-in-recyclerview-and-pass-it-between)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can pass the item in arguments as below:

```
   private fun clickOnPopularProduct(view: View, product: Producten) {
    val transaction = requireFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    val productInfoFragment = ProductInfoFragment()

    **//(psuedocode)
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putExtra(“product”, //pass your product item here)
    productInfoFragment.arguments = bundle**

    transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, productInfoFragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()

}
```

In onCreateView of your ProductInfoFragment you can call after inflating layout:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    productInfoViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProductInfoViewModel::class.java)

    getArgs()

    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_info, container, false)


    …
     return root
}

private fun getArgs() {

  //here you can extract your extra(psedocode)
  geselecteerdeProduct = arguments?.getExtra(“product") 
}
```

Similarly in this method:

```
private fun click() {

}
```

You should pass the product in arguments to the next fragment.

Comment: `transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, productInfoFragment)` if you are using NavHostFragment and Jetpack Navigation, then you are not supposed to replace the NavHostFragment. You are supposed to use the `navigation.xml` to navigate between fragments.

Comment: I see now that this idea is inherited from the question, but the question's code was already incorrect. The idea of using `setArguments()` instead of a field variable is definitely an improvement, though.