# Android Kotlin get data from a clicked item in Recyclerview and pass it between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

So I have two data classes (`OutletListDataClass` and `ProductListDataClass`) that are currently used by two different fragments (`OutletListFragment.kt` and `ProductListFragment.kt`, directly connected in navigation graph.).

Both of there fragments are RecyclerView. I want to extract the information from clicked item in `OutletListFragment.kt` (That contained in the two data classes) and pass it to `ProductListFragment.kt`.

These are the data classes I use in both fragments:

**OutletListDataClass**

```
data class OutletListPOJODataClasses(

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    var data: List<OutletListPOJODataClassesDataItem>? = null,

    @SerializedName("error")
    val error: OutletListDataClassError? = null
)



data class OutletListPOJODataClassesDataItem(
    @SerializedName("stk_prodcode")//Both data classes have this variable
    @Expose
    val stkProdcode: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("stk_allqty")
    @Expose
    val stkAllqty: Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("skt_lastupdate")
    @Expose
    val sktLastupdate: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("outlet_address")
    @Expose
    val outletAddress: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("outlet_name")
    @Expose
    val outletName: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("stk_outcode")
    @Expose
    val stkOutcode: String? = null
)
```

**ProductListDataClass**

```
data class ProductListPOJODataClasses(

    @field:SerializedName("data")
    val data: List<ProductListPOJODataClassesDataItem?>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("error")
    val error: ProductListDataClassError? = null
)

data class ProductListDataClassError(

    @field:SerializedName("msg")
    val msg: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("code")
    val code: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status")
    val status: Boolean? = null
)

data class ProductListPOJODataClassesDataItem(
    @field:SerializedName("stk_prodcode")  //Both data classes have this variable
    val stkProdcode: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("stk_allqty")
    val stkAllqty: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("pro_saleprice")
    val proSaleprice: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("skt_lastupdate")
    val sktLastupdate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("stk_outcode")
    val stkOutcode: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("pro_name")
    val proName: String? = null
)
```

As You can see, these two data Classes contains the sa.me variable (StkOutcode). And That's what I want to extract (From `OutletListDataItem`)

Here's the code snippet of the current `OutletListFragment.kt`:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Product List"

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_product_stock_outlet_list,
        container,
        false
    )

    //Show Progressbar While loading data
    showProgressBar()

    //Apply layout manager
    binding.rvOutletList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager((activity as AppCompatActivity))

    //Fetch Outlet List Data
    fetchOutletListData()

    // Declare that this fragment has menu
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    // Set action bar title to "Outlet List"
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Outlet List"

    return binding.root
}
```

And this is the recyclerview adapter I created for OutletListFragment.
**OutletListAdapter**

```
 class OutletListItemHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bind(
        outlet: OutletListPOJODataClassesDataItem,
        clickListener: OutletListOnItemClickListener?
    ) {
        itemView.outletName.text = outlet.outletName

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener?.onItemClicked(outlet)
        }
    }
}

class OutletListAdapter(private var outletList: OutletListPOJODataClasses, private val itemClickListener: OutletListOnItemClickListener)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<OutletListItemHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OutletListItemHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.outlet_list_item_layout, parent, false)
        return OutletListItemHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = outletList.data!!.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OutletListItemHolder, position: Int) {
        val outlet = outletList.data?.get(position)
        if (outlet != null) {
            holder.bind(outlet, itemClickListener)
        }
    }
}


interface OutletListOnItemClickListener{
    fun onItemClicked(outlet: OutletListPOJODataClassesDataItem)
}
```

How I can get the variable I want from the Data class in `OutletListFragment.kt` and pass it to `ProductListFragment.kt` ? If there's anything unclear, let me know.

**Edit:**

This is the snippet of the `navigation.xml`:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/productStockOutletList"
    android:name="something.mainFragments.ProductStockOutletListFragment"
    android:label="ProductStockOutletList" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_productStockOutletList_to_productListFragment"
        app:destination="@id/productListFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:exitAnim="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
        app:popEnterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/productListFragment"
    android:name="something.mainFragments.ProductListFragment"
    android:label="ProductListFragment" />
```

Comment: Navigation graph? So we can assume that you are using Jetpack Navigation and have a corresponding `navigation.xml`? Because then you set it as arguments over the `<action` that leads from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB`, then use the `NavController` to navigate.

Comment: So.... how can I extract the information of the clicked item from recyclerview `outletListFragment.kt` ?

Comment: Well, didn't you implement `OutletListOnItemClickListener` on your Fragment and pass it to the adapter? Btw you should be using `getAdapterPosition()` (and check `position >= 0` instead of relying on the item you got from `bind`, this can cause cryptic bugs).

Comment: So what should i add in the adapter? Sorry I'm quite new in android development.

Comment: The trick is that what you need to add goes in `navigation.xml`, and you have to call it from `OutletListFragment` in your custom click listener implementation thing. Assuming you really are using Jetpack Navigation, and navigation graphs. There are about 4 different ways to navigate with fragments, and this detail is crucial.

Comment: Oh sorry. let me edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Jetpack Navigation (and as you are referring to things like "navigation graphs", so clearly you are using Jetpack Navigation), then to pass arguments between navigation destinations, you must define an `<action` with the right `arguments` that is then passed as some variant of parcelable data to the other fragment.

This is the example from [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#define_destination_arguments):

> ```
> <action android:id="@+id/startMyFragment"
>     app:destination="@+id/myFragment">
>     <argument
>         android:name="myArg"
>         app:argType="integer"
>         android:defaultValue="1" />
> </action>
> ```

So in your case, it should like you need something like

```
<navigation ...>
    <action android:id="@+id/toProductListFragment"
        app:destination="@+id/productListFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="stkProdcode"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>
```

Apparently this stuff only works if you also enable the `safeargs` plugin (as otherwise you have to "remember" this key yourself, or write the `NavDirections` class by hand, or put together the `Bundle` yourself - either way, Jetpack Navigation expects you to use Safeargs to pass arguments):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.2.2"
```

And

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

And then you should be able to do

```
class OutletListFragment: Fragment(), OutletListOnItemClickListener {
    ....

    override fun onItemClicked(outlet: OutletListPOJODataClassesDataItem) {
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(NavigationDirections.toProductListFragment(outlet.stkProdcode))
    }
}
```

And due to limitations of Jetpack Navigation, you also have to duplicate the argument definition into the `<fragment` tag as well:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/productListFragment"
    android:name="com.example.switchingandroidappproject.mainFragments.ProductListFragment"
    android:label="ProductListFragment" >
    <argument
        android:name="stkProdcode"
        app:argType="string" />
</fragment>
```

Make sure not to make a typo (`android:name` mismatch) as you'd run into unexpected failures).

Now you can obtain your arguments on the other side as

```
val args = ProductListFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments())
val code = args.stkProdcode
```

I don't really use Jetpack Navigation, so I'm surprised to see that you have to duplicate the fragment args to the action args, but there you have it.

---

...to think with [what I use in place of Jetpack Navigation](https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack-ftue-sample/blob/4392b650eb8b98ef8430ddeb5c4cf7cfe0dd0e25/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestackftuesample/features/registration/RegistrationViewModel.kt#L63), this is as simple as

```
// send
backstack.goTo(ProductListScreen(stkProdCode))
// receive
val prodCode = getKey<ProductListScreen>().stkProdCode
```

And is just as (if not more) type-safe.  *grumble* *grumble* but that doesn't help your case, that's not Jetpack Navigation.

Comment: It returns "Unresolved reference: NavigationDirections" in the `OutletListFragment`

Comment: Well, did you add the `<action` at top-level of `navigation.xml`, and the safeargs plugin `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"` to your `build.gradle`?

Comment: If you have just added `safeargs` plugin, you'll have to also do `Rebuild project` for this file to appear.

Comment: I see. Finally I did connect both Fragments without error. But variable "code" returns empty in the `ProductListFragment.kt`

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215229/discussion-between-dimas-hermanto-and-epicpandaforce).